# Count how many times a substring from list appears in a string

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
seq = '01234567890123456789'
```

that I want to first break up into intervals of 4. I found a previous answer

```
n = 4    
[seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(seq,n)]
```

which gives me

```
['0123', '4567', '8901', '2345', '6789']
```

And now I want to compare my chunked up string to every entry in a list of substrings:

```
mylist = ['0123', '1111' '2345']
```

and return an array that counts how many times each substring appeared in the original string. I see a lot of examples of finding one substring in a larger string but I'm confused as to how to do this with a list of substrings

Comment: Looks like you're trying to find the answer to your problem, rather than trying to figure out how to solve your problem.  I think you need to look at basic array processing tutorials to understand how to work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
generated = ['0123', '4567', '8901', '2345', '6789']
mylist =  ['0123', '1111' '2345']
result = [generated.count(element) for element in mylist ]
```

`list.count(e)` returns number of occurrences of `e` in `list`, so we can execute it for each item in `mylist`.

In this case result is `[1,0,1]` which means `'0123'` appeared in `generated` once, `'1111'` did not appear and `'2345'` appeared once as well.

Couldn't figure out from your description which way you want to compare occurrences. If I got it the wrong way around just say and I'll be happy to edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
chunked = ['0123', '4567', '8901', '2345', '6789']
mylist = ['0123', '1111', '2345']
my_count = {}
for m in mylist:
   for c in chunked:
      if m == c:
          try:
              my_count[m] += 1
          except KeyError:
              my_count[m] = 1

>>> chunked
['0123', '4567', '8901', '2345', '6789']
>>> mylist
['0123', '1111', '2345']
>>> my_count
{'2345': 1, '0123': 1}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq = '01234567890123456789'
chunks = ['0123', '4567', '8901', '2345', '6789']
dict = {}
for elt in chunks:
    dict[elt] = seq.count(elt)

print(dict)
```

Comment: {'2345': 2, '4567': 2, '6789': 2, '0123': 2, '8901': 1}